# Capistrano - Carrierwave LoadError: cannot load such file -- carrierwave/processing/mime_types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, capistrano

When I run cap production deploy I keep running into this error with carrier wave. I have posted my carrierwave settings below.

```
Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@104.236.193.148: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- carrierwave/processing/mime_types
 /home/deploy/aldrinclement/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-         4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
 /home/deploy/aldrinclement/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
 /home/deploy/aldrinclement/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
 /home/deploy/aldrinclement/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
 /home/deploy/aldrinclement/releases/20170103201423/app/uploaders/author_image_uploader.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Carrierwave.rb

```
if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
        provider:                   'AWS',
        aws_access_key_id:         Rails.application.secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key:     Rails.application.secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region:                    Settings.aws_region
    }
    config.fog_directory = Settings.aws_s3_bucket_name
    config.permissions = 0666
    config.directory_permissions = 0777
    config.storage = :fog
  end
end

CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^[:word:]\.\-\+]/
```

My secrets.yml has the AWS keys defined  - I had run into missing aws keys and solved that issue with secrets.yml symlinked in my deploy.rb file. I'm using carrierwave 1.0.0 in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

mime_types file has been removed from carrierwave, see [commit](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/commit/947eee5bf58051bedec8b63a44aa5d3c53988e16).

You do likely have `require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'` on the top of `app/uploaders/author_image_uploader.rb`. You need to either remove carrierwave mime_types references from the project and switch to [mime-types](https://github.com/mime-types/ruby-mime-types/) gem which is a runtime dependency of carrierwave now or rollback to the previous carrierwave version.

Comment: Got past that error but now I'm getting this:   
00:32 passenger:restart
      01 passenger-config restart-app /home/deploy/aldrinclement/current --ignore-app-not-running
      01 There are no Phusion Passenger-served applications running whose paths begin with '/home/deploy/aldrinclement/current'.
      01